# accept_nested_attributes_for + reject_if + display error for unsaved child objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a 'Parent' has-many 'Children' relationship among 2 models. i m using accept_nested_attributes_for n the 'reject_if' feature. i want to display the a error message as "2 Child objects could not be saved." when the parent model is saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `validates_associated` to bring up  validation errors if any of the children are invalid. I think if you are using `reject_if` it won't actually build the child object, so you might need to remove the `reject_if` condition for the validation errors on the child to be shown.

```
Class Parent
  has_many :children
  validates_associated :children
end

class Child
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

More info here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html