# Rails form validation for custom setter during update_attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a setup similar to below. Everything works fine, but if the validations in the `Employee` model fail (when the custom setter is invoked), how do I get them to fire when `update_attributes` is called on the `Employer` model?

#### views/employers/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @employer %>
    <% @employer.employees.each do |employee| %>
        <%= fields_for "employer[employee_attributes][]", employee do |e| %>
            # FORM HERE
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

#### model/employer.rb

```
attr_accessible :employee_attributes
has_many :employees

def employee_attributes=(employee_attributes)
    employee_attributes.each_pair{|id,attributes|
        employee = Employee.find(id)
        employee.update_attributes(attributes)
    }
end
```

### Solution:

As per sockmonks answer below call `employee.update_attributes!(attributes)` instead (with the bang at the end). This raises an exception.

Then in `Employer` controller

#### controllers/employers_controller.rb

```
def update
    @employer = Employer.find(:id)
    begin
        @employer.update_attributes(params[:employer])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
        # Handle Error(s)
    end
end
```

Comment: You want each associated Employee record to be validated whenever you update the attributes of an Employer record?

Comment: That is correct, because the employer form indubitably has employee data. This is a simplified example of a more complex issue I'm tackling.

Comment: Hmm no to be more specific, I want the Employer update_attributes to fail if the changes made in the custom setter fail. So not a persistent validation between the two models, only when the setter is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling employee.update_attributes(attributes), use employee.update_attributes!(attributes) instead. (Note the bang at the end of the method name.) That way if any employee is invalid, an exception will be raised.

Now whereever you're calling that custom setter, be sure to wrap it in a transaction, and rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid. Then if any employees are invalid, the whole transaction will be rolled back, and you'll have a chance to gracefully handle passing the validation errors back to the user.

Comment: if you rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => ex, I know you can call ex.full_messages to get the string messages, or ex.record to get the specific invalid record. If you need something else, just inspect that exception object or play with it in the rails console, you should be above to find what you're looking for.

Comment: Ya I edited my comment after reading the docs. You can just call `ex.record.errors`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can declare [validates_associated](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated) validation to achieve that.

Comment: This doesn't work. The update for the `Employee` fails, but the `update_attributes` for the `Employer` still succeeds so I can't flash an error.

Answer (score 0):

As ck3g pointed out, you should be using the `validates_associated` method for validating your children objects. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754565/accept-nested-attributes-for-reject-if-display-error-for-unsaved-child-objec) has an example of that.

Rails also has hooks for saving your parent and children objects with a single call (e.g. `@employer.save`): [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).